# Cassanda cql issue : "Batch too large","code":8704

Tags: node.js, cassandra, windows-dev-center, datastax-devcenter

I am getting the below error in select query.

> {"error":{"name":"ResponseError","info":"Represents an error message from the server","message":"Batch too large","code":8704,"coordinator":"10.29.96.106:9042"}}

Comment: What does the select query look like?  How many SELECTs are in the batch?

Comment: select * from user_request_by_country_by_processworkflow WHERE created_on <= '2022-01-08T16:19:07+05:30' ALLOW FILTERING;

Comment: If result is more than 1000 it is showing this error

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I get it; you're using Dev Center.

> If result is more than 1000 it is showing this error

Yes, that's Dev Center preventing you from running queries that can hurt your cluster.  Like this:

```
select * from user_request_by_country_by_processworkflow
WHERE created_on <= '2022-01-08T16:19:07+05:30' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

`ALLOW FILTERING` is a way to force Cassandra to read multiple partitions in one query, even though it is designed to warn you against doing that.  If you really need to run a query like this, then you'll want to build a table with a PRIMARY KEY designed to specifically support that.

In this case, I'd recommend "bucketing" your table data by whichever time component keeps the partitions within a reasonable size.  For example, if the day keeps the rows-per-partition below 50k, the primary key definition would look like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (day,created_on)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_on DESC);
```

Then, a query that would work and be allowed would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_request_by_country_by_processworkflow
WHERE day=20220108
  AND created_on <= '2022-01-08T16:19:07+05:30';
```

In summary:

- Don't run multi-partition queries.
- Don't use `ALLOW FILTERING`.
- Do build tables to match queries.
- Do use time buckets to keep partitions from growing unbounded.

Comment: Problem here is i can't change it because it is existing table and used so many places. So do u have any workaround or is it possible to use limit option with allow filter as workaround

Comment: @Sumant  You could try using Spark.  A distributed query layer on top of Cassandra is one way to run OLAP based queries like this.